# Rounded views not working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I have a code that takes a view and rounds it corners - turning it into a circle:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 8)];
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

This works great on iOS 7 and iOS 8 - but doesn't work on iOS 9.
How can I fix it?

Comment: If this is really not working, my apps will crash :/

Comment: It's not crashing - but it stays rectangle

Comment: I just checked, but it does work. can you change  dot.frame.size.width/2 to  say 4?

Comment: I tried to hardcode cornerRadius to 5

Comment: The code above does work as expected for me. Please provide a minimal reproducible example that shows the problem.

Comment: That's probably because you're trying to set the corner radius before the object is actually created, probably moving `imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2;` to `viewWillAppear:` or `layoutSubviews` would work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out adding a background color to the ImageView fixes the issue...

Comment: It must be a proper color once clearColor won't work.

Comment: I've spent 30 minutes on this, WHY? This is so stupid!

Comment: Thanks a lot. So strange bug.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @YogevSitton answer I've searched over docs and found this:

It appears to be something in [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410818-cornerradius):

> By default, the corner radius does not apply to the image in the
>   layer’s contents property; it applies only to the background color and
>   border of the layer.

So, to set cornerRadius to UIImageView it needs to have backgroundColor.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not working for anymore, make a component. Subclass from UIView. Do this changes on this subclass:

```
subclass.layer.cornerRadius = subclass.frame.size.width/2;
subclass.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

and add the imageView to this view. This will solve the problem.

```
@implementation CircleImageView{

    UIImageView* imageView;
    CGFloat width;

}

- (instancetype) initWithTopLeft:(CGPoint)topLeft width:(CGFloat)wdth{

    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, wdth, wdth)];
    if (self) {
        width = wdth;

        [self createContent];

        self.layer.cornerRadius = width/2.;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) createContent{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width)];
    [self addSubview:imageView];

}
```

Comment: How can you know that this will solve a problem if you don't know the cause of the problem?

Comment: I'm using my circle imageViews like this, because there was some bug once, when I could not set imageView's cornerRadius.

Comment: You do set the layer's corner radius the same way as he does. Why should this work on a subclass of UIImage but not on UIImage in iOS 9?

Comment: This is not a subclass of UIImage. This custom class is inherited from UIView. I set this view's cornerRadius and properties, not imageView's. This working for sure

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **Quartzcore.framework** in Linked  **Framework and Libraries**

then importing the same in your viewController.m file

Answer (score 0):

I jsut subClass UIImageView ,like this ,I use PureLayout control the imageView,like below:

```
[imageViewIcon autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeft toEdge:ALEdgeLeft ofView:self.contentView withOffset:20];
[imageViewIcon autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeTop ofView:self.contentView withOffset:10];
[imageViewIcon autoPinEdge:ALEdgeBottom toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:self.contentView withOffset:-10];
[imageViewIcon autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionHeight toDimension:ALDimensionWidth ofView:imageViewIcon];




-(instancetype)init
{
if (self = [super init]) {

}

return self;
}
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];
[self layoutIfNeeded];

self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.layer.cornerRadius = self.width*0.5;



}
```